# Hibernate and DB2 on z/OS - auto-create table

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, zos

my current problem is that I want to use Hibernate on DB2 to do this nice ORM-stuff and it somehow works, but not really like I want it to ..
The core of the problem is that I can only connect to a DB2-subsystem via JDBC and have to specify the database in which to create the table in the SQL-query, which seems to be missing in Hibernate - since the table is created, but in some kind of auto-created database.
Is there some way to append a " in database [...]" to the DDL or sth. similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution by extending the DB2Dialect:

```
public class DB2Dialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect {
    public static String db;

    @Override
    public String getTableTypeString() {
        return " IN DATABASE " + db;
    }
}
```

And since the comment for this function implies that it's designated to a MySQL feature, I guess it's fine for the moment.

Comment: This seems wrong somehow.  I have no doubt this might work, but it doesn't feel like the right way to do this.  I mean, you shouldn't be installing this (tables should already be created/administered).  And assuming it's "fine for the moment" just means it's going to bite you when you least expect it.  You may want to talk to your DBAs - the other versions of DB2 seem to push everything into a default "user" schema for the database the session is connected to, I'm surprised that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I agree that it's not the best solution, but I don't see any other option so far after looking at the Hibernate sources. Concerning the Schema: I actually wrote a Driver that that uses the official Driver and fills in some options like user, password and schema - kind of making it possible to forget about table spaces and this stuff. It's just a little project for devs who want to try it out in a test environment - surely nothing critical.